# How is U1 powered in this schematic

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

This is taken from an app-note on the [ONSemi NCP1014](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1010-D.PDF). Pin 1 of the NCP1014 is Vcc, and I don't understand how it is powered in this configuration. The datasheet linked above mentioned a dynamic self supply powered by charging a cap on Vcc but I'm really not sure how that works given the polarity of D5. Is current drawn through C4/5 here, charging those *and* C7 on the Vcc, then C7 discharged to power the device?

[The App note](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/DN06011-D.PDF) also mentioned that D6 is only there for a fail condition and when activated would blow F1.

[image: Schematic of non-isolated buck configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet- figure 2 and especially the below description from your linked datasheet are pretty self-explanatory.. ask if there is anything that is not clear.

[image]

When the MOSFET is off the current source shown in the above diagram charges C7 through the output caps until it reaches the proper voltage. This does mean that a small load is required or the output voltage could go high out of regulation and either that load or D6 can perform that function.

Answer (score 2):

From the datasheet you linked to:

> Vcc: This pin is connected to an external capacitor of typically 10 mF. The natural ripple superimposed on the VCC participates to the frequency jittering. For improved standby performance, an auxiliary VCC can be connected to Pin 1. The VCC also includes an active shunt which serves as an opto fail−safe protection.

So it doesn't need a separate supply to that pin - it gets the supply internally and the capacitor is used to stabilize it.

But where does it come from?  Well, the internal block diagram in the same datasheet shows that quite plainly:

[image]

Yes, it gets it from the drain of the internal switching MOSFET, which is presented on pin 3 of the SOT-223 packaged device.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that the negative rail of the input is still about 55 to 240V lower than the negative rail of the output, so even though the chip isn't being supplied a normal positive supply rail it is still able to extract enough energy from the circuit for its operation.